# Как в Android Studio отметить методы(сделать закладки)?

Tags: java, android

Погуглил, но не могу найти инфы. Не могу сформулировать, что мне нужно. Но суть такая. Можно ли в студии как то отметить функции в избранное? Вот у меня код на 1000 строк можно ли как то выбрать 3, 4 функции для быстрого поиска, чтоб не скролить код вниз вверх в поисках нужного метода?

Comment: Ну... Можно поставить `//TODO` и тогда справа будет синенькая полосочка при клике на кою вас будет проскроливать до неё...\

Comment: F11 ставит закладки, shift+F11 их вызывает

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Я присоединяюсь к комментарию  Abrog Petrovich в Android Studio, как и в IDEA есть bookmarks  - закладки. Вы можете ставить их находясь на строчке клавишей F11 и открывать окно bookmark сочетанием shift+F11.

Хочу добавить, что их очень удобно добавлять клавишей Ctrl + ЛКлавишаМыши рядом с номером строки и также удобно без окна вызывать их, переключаясь клавишей мыши на черный скролл справа, быстрое перемещение.

Comment: Так же их можно ставить ctrl+shit+цифра и переходить по ctrl+цифра

Comment: очень удобно, спасибо.